# Names of 33 Gods and their Jobs (including goddesses)?

Tags: gods, goddess

I know they are 33 Gods already some people ask How many Gods? My Question is Who Are 33 Gods and their Roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Eight Vasus** (Deities of elements)

1. Dyaus : Sky
2. Prithivi : Earth
3. Vayu : Wind
4. Agni : Fire
5. Nakshatra : Stars
6. Antariksha : Space
7. Surya : Sun
8. Chandra : Moon

**Twelve Adityas** (personified deities)

9. Vishnu : The presever
10. Indra : Leader of other Adityas and god of clouds
11. Ansh : Due share
12. Aryaman : Nobility
13. Bhaag : Due inheritance
14. Dhatri : Ritual skill
15. Tvashtar : Skill in crafting
16. Mitra : Friendship
17. Pushan/Ravi : Prosperity
18. Savitra/Parjanya : Power of word
19. Surya/Vivasvan : Social law
20. Varun : Fate
21. Vaman : Cosmic law

    (Adityas may vary).

**Eleven Rudras** (The five abstractions)

22. Ananda : Bliss
23. Vijnana : Knowledge
24. Manas : Thought
25. Prana : Breath or life
26. Vack : Speech

**Five names** of Śiva

27. Isana : Revealing grace
28. Tatpurusha : Concealing grace
29. Aghora : Dissolution/rejuvenation
30. Vamadeva : Preserving aspect
31. Sadyojata : Born at once
32. Atma : Self

And the last

33. The two Ashwins : Twin solar deities.

Answer (score 1):

Human race is still not in a position to describe the super consciousness, to make it understandable atleast to some degree is defined by the term GOD, and so is its nature, that it cannot be conceived fully by mind or by words or writing or by any means, rather than everything can be used to describe about some of its attribute.

People, religion, etc to all, God appears in many forms, and those forms form the different numbers like 3,33, 33 crores etc, everything being the same truth. To realise this fully, one must go beyond mind, conciousness, or bhakti ..multiple levels, till then they appear as multiple to our small mind...

So as per Rigveda, 33 gods consists of the 12 Adityas, the 8 Vasus, the 11 Rudras and the 2 Ashvins.

Answer (score 1):

User anup has given the answer "So as per Rigveda, 33 gods consists of the 12 Adityas, the 8 Vasus, the 11 Rudras and the 2 Ashvins" but there is still a school of thought that says that there are 33,00,00,000 (thirty three crores)deities in Sanatana Dharma. Various scripture refer to 33 koti devi / devatas and 'koti' means crores (ten million=one crore). However another schoolof thought accept the Rig Vedic classification of gods into 33 gods comprising 12 Adityas, 8 Vasus, 11 Rudras and 2 Ashvinis.